# Carrierwave returning wrong file sizes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have the following model:

```
class Asset < ApplicationRecord
  ## Associations ##
  belongs_to :assetable, polymorphic: true, optional: true

  ## Validations ##
  validate { |a| a.blank_to_nil :description }
  validate :file_size

  ## Callbacks ##
  before_save :default_attrs

  ## Misc ##
  mount_base64_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader

  ## Methods ##
  def version_url(ver)
    return nil unless attachment.versions[:images].send(ver)
    attachment.versions[:images].send(ver).url
  end

  private

  def assetable_const
    assetable_type.constantize
  end

  def attachment_size
    attachment.size
  end

  def assetable_max_file_size
    return 0.0 unless assetable_type
    assetable_type.constantize.max_file_size
  end

  def default_attrs
    self.alt = default_file_name if alt.blank?
    self.title = default_file_name if title.blank?
  end

  def default_file_name
    "#{default_assetable_name}-#{default_assetable_stamp}"
  end

  def default_assetable_name
    "#{assetable_type.downcase}-#{assetable_id}"
  end

  def default_assetable_stamp
    "#{Time.now.strftime('%d%m%y')}-#{attachment.filename}"
  end

  # for now add to attachment and title
  # error doesnt show on CMS under attachment
  def file_size
    return if attachment_size.to_f <= assetable_max_file_size.megabyte.to_f
    errors.add(
      :attachment,
      I18n.t(
        'validations.assets.max_file_size',
        value: assetable_max_file_size.to_s
      )
    )
  end
end
```

My problem comes from the last method, validating the file size. I have a separate method in each model that includes assets, max_file_size:

```
class Content::Panels::ImageOnly < Content::Panel
  ## Includes ##
  include Assetable

  ## Associations ##
  belongs_to :panel_holder, polymorphic: true

  ## Validations ##
  validates_presence_of :asset

  ## Misc ##
  set_assetables :asset

  ## Methods ##
  def self.max_file_size
    1.0
  end
```

I'm uploading the image I've attached - 680 KB. When I put a binding.pry in my 'file_size' method, I can see the attachment.size returns a value over 1MB:

```
pry(#<Asset>)> attachment.size.to_f
=> 2481189.0
```

Is this value being returned in bits of bytes? If bits it appears it's half the real file size (which may be possible due to compression magic) but I'd assumed it would return bytes..

My method fails every time unless I increase the max file size:

```
def max_file_size
  3.0
end
```

Setting it to 3MB makes the validation pass. 2MB fails. Any help is greatly appreciated

EDIT: Image being uploaded:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NY7c.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else losing their mind - tested with various different files - file size seems to come back in bits.